# numpy.power between 2 integers is negative

Tags: python, numpy, math, negative-number

Why the pow between 2 integers returns a negative value? This is my code:

```
print(obj[10,47])
[  0   0 170]#RGB value of the pixel
np.power(5,obj[10,47, 2])
-4029119841745550215
np.power(5,170)
1727233711018888925077270372560079914223200072887256277004740694033718360632485411594301500694457645312109458789229932719399019789366389338730600755411619549372494220733642578125
```

As you can see, the second operation returns the correct answer using the same values. I tried with different type op `pow` operation, in this code I used `Numpy.power(base, exponent)`

I solved the issue: the problem was the type of the data.

```
np.pow(x, y, dtype=np.longdouble)
```

Comment: Shouldn't you replace `obj[10,47, 3]` with `obj[10,47, 2]` ? (the indices start at 0, so the 3rd coordinate has index 2)

Comment: (but if this is the answer I still don't see why it's negative, you should have either an exception for going out of the array or a positive one that is `5^(some other pixel, probably obj[10, 48, 0])`)...

Comment: I corrected the index here in the post (in my code was correct).

Comment: could you please try `np.power(5,int(obj[10,47, 2]))`?

Comment: I am trying to process images and so, I want to convert a pixel into a unique value (2**R * 3**G * 5**B). But with some of these pixel I have a wrong answer.

Comment: I already tried with this casting but it doesn't work

Comment: Are you sure `np.power(5, 170)` alone returns that value? It returns
 -4029119841745550215 for me and on [ideone](https://ideone.com/sRbPKV) too (due to overflow). Besides, `5**170` is 66819117752304891153513411678787046970379922002626217449048437304009966024678258966762456338983611203730106353759765625 which is different from the value you claim is correct.

Comment: Is it not just an integer overflow problem ?

Comment: Also, pandas does not implement its own power function for computation, it defers to NumPy (unless you're talking about a different pandas library).

Comment: It's clearly a problem of data types: `np.power(5, 170, dtype=np.longdouble)`
returns the right answer (up to the 19th digit)

Comment: Ok, I made a mistake copying the last result. But as I said, I use different approaches, such as a**b. Here, 5**170 is different from  5**obj[10,47, 2]

Comment: I edited the title and tags, because this is about NumPy's `power` operation rather than Python's `pow` operation.

Comment: @Luca I think you need to use an arbitrary-precision integer data type instead of the default (fixed precision) type.